# How to configure Postgres to never rotate or truncate a log file?

Tags: postgresql

I have a very very old Postgres version 9.2.23 DB that has very little log activity. I want to prevent any logs from being deleted. Currently the `log_collector` is configured to rotate the logs every day and truncate on rotation. Here are the current settings in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/postgresql.conf`:

```
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'  
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 0
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
```

Here's my plan for re-configuring the logging so they're never deleted:

1. Create a new log file: `touch /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_log/perpetual.log`
2. Set `log_filename = 'perpetual.log'`
3. Set `log_rotation_age = 0`
4. And just for good measure, set `log_truncate_on_rotation = off`
5. Restart Postgres

Will this plan work? Is there an easier way?